# The connection of clauses

Tags: meaning, i-adjectives, sentence

> 大豆は他の作物が育ちにくい、やせた土地で栽培できるので、昔から日本各地で栽培されてきた。

Please help me understand the meaning of the sentence.

To me it looks like 大豆は他の作物が育ちにくい is a separate sentence, not connected with the rest. But it should be. If it is connected, why isn't にくい connected like an I-adjective （にくくて）？

Could you please translate the whole given sentence.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the sentence would break down as follows:

大豆は　{[他の作物が育ちにくい]、[やせた]土地}　で栽培できるので、昔から日本各地で栽培されてきた。

Where there are two equal priority adjective clauses that modify 土地. In regards to the lack of ～くて form to connect these two descriptors look [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/63211/whats-the-difference-in-nuance-between-multiple-%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E8%A9%9E-%E3%81%84-adjectives-with-and-wit) at the second bullet point in the correct answer. A comma is inserted to sound more formal, which I think matches the sentence's topic and grammer.

for a translation, I would say something like:

"Since soybeans can be cultivated in infertile soil that is difficult for other crops to grow in, from long ago soybeans came to be grown all over Japan".