# What's the rule for expressing "I don't want to"

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliaries

As far as I know, for expressing you want to do something, you have to just attach たい to the verb stem like in カニを食べたい。

Then, what's the rule for saying "I don't want to". I've seen in this phrase 怖い映画は、見たくないよ , they added "たくない" to the verb stem, but is that always so, or how is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, that's exactly right.

V-stem + たい     "Want to V"

V-stem + たくない "(I) don't want to V"

[Source](http://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-expression-desire.html)

Answer (score 10):

Adding to @ishikun's answer, you need to note that [たい](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84) is an (auxiliary) adjective which uses 'adjective stem (い removed from い adjective) + くない' to [negate it](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/adjectives).

I would say

> They added "くない" to the adjective stem.

rather than

> They added "たくない" to the verb stem.

You will find the linked question interesting. [In what way is the negative form of a verb an adjective?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4746/in-what-way-is-the-negative-form-of-a-verb-an-adjective/5110#5110)

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other answers, if you want to make a contrastive/emphatic statement, you can of course add a は or も before the ない.

> - 朝食を抜きたく**は**ないけど、今出かけないと電車に間に合わないよ。　→　I don't *want* to skip breakfast, but if I don't leave now I'll miss the train.
> - 行きたく**も**残りたく**も**ない　→　I don't want to stay or go.
> - ライブを見逃したく**は**ないけど、おばあさんの面倒を見ないとだめだから、行きようがない。　→　It's not that I want to miss the concert, but I have to take care of my grandmother, so there's no way I can go.

Comment: In other words, it's important to realize that ない is still a separate word here.

Comment: @snailplane It's pretty obvious if you use the polite form: 行きたくありません