# Can this case of “〜は” be replaced by “〜を”?

Tags: particle-は

I saw a rather interesting sentence:

> ミンメイ様は客は兄様しか取っていなかったらしい

In particular, the use of “客は兄様しか” interests me as the “〜は” does not seem to be contrastive and “客は” comes before “兄様しか”, seemingly giving “取る” two objects. So is “客を兄様しか” also grammatically possible here, and if not, what kind of grammatical role exactly does this “客は” here fulfill and could it then be replaced by “〜が” perhaps?

Comment: `〜を` possible, `〜が` not.

Comment: 「肉は鶏肉しか食べない」みたいな感じですかね？「肉を食べる」「鶏肉を食べる」は言えますが「肉を鶏肉を食べる」はおかしいですね

Comment: It might help to see 〜しか as adverbially modifying a negative predicate. This is kind of related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/100242/43676